# Multivariable Calculus Curvature

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Find an equation for the circle of curvature of the curve r(t) = t**i** +(sint)**j** at the point (pi/2,1). (The curve parametrizes the graph of y= sin(x) in the xy-plane.)

I know the answer is (x- pi/2)$^2$ + y$^2$ =1;

I have computed all the components of getting the correct answer: r(t), v, |v|, |v(t)|, dT/dt, and *k*.

What I don't know is how to piece these together in a coherent way to reach the answer.

(1) Why is the centre at (pi/2, 0)?

(2) How is curvature relevant to this problem? Curvature is defined as |d**T**/ds|: how fast the tangent is changing with respect to change along the curve, but how is that relevant to the equation of the circle?

(3) Why is radius equivalent to 1/*k*? I've played around with equations but I can't reach this conclusion. Thank you very much for any comment.

Comment: the curvature can be calculated as $k=||r''||$ if $||r'||=1$